# spring.profiles.active=native is not working on app.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, config

I keep getting the:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository"

every time I try to run the app.

Already tried to set the `spring.profiles.active=native`, but it keeps not working.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: file:///${user.home}/config
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository

Comment: You should pass that as command line argument or use spring.profiles.include = native

Comment: It worked! TYVM!

Comment: Even when this is old... thanks so much @Deadpool ... I have been looking for this simple but powerful answer for 2 hours. You should add your comment as an answer to allow Pedro to accept it. Of course I will up vote it too.